# Unable to get parseFrom as an available method from generated proto

Tags: scala, protocol-buffers, proto

My build.sbt is

```
PB.targets in Compile := Seq(

  PB.gens.java -> (sourceManaged in Compile).value,

  scalapb.gen(javaConversions = true) -> (sourceManaged in Compile).value

)

libraryDependencies += "com.thesamet.scalapb" %% "scalapb-runtime" % scalapb.compiler.Version.scalapbVersion % "protobuf"
```

My scalapb.sbt is this.

addSbtPlugin("com.thesamet" % "sbt-protoc" % "0.99.19")

libraryDependencies += "com.thesamet.scalapb" %% "compilerplugin" % "0.8.1"

Answer (score 0):

Just change `% "protobuf"` to `% "compile"`